# Fragment not getting deleted visually

Tags: android-fragments, android

I am trying to replace a Fragment with a new Fragment. For this I used following code.

> transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,
>   newFragment);

But on viewing in AVD, its not actually getting replaced. newFragment(which is smaller in size) is displayed on top of old_fragment.

However on again accessing old_fragment it returns null.

I even tried

> Fragment oldFragment =
>   getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.home_fragment);
>   transaction.remove(oldFragment);

Even this is not removing Fragment visually.

Could you please help me in actually removing any Fragment.

P.S.: I am using Android Compatibility Pack and building it for android 2.2.

Comment: You are calling `transaction.commit()` aren't you?

Comment: Yes I am, thats why its showing newFragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is some kind of behavior with Android Fragments.

If you have any Fragment added in XML Layout, then Fragments on that activity can't be removed. However it works correctly if all the Fragments are added dynamically.

Strange isn't it?

for reference please see.
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b56967e0f147168d